# Shutdown timer(Sinvise) cannot detect network adapter

Tags: automation, shutdown

I'm using shutdown timer from sinvise to automatically shutdown my desktop if the download is done.
But it seems that it cannot detect my network adapter very well.
I know because I was also using shutdown timer on my laptop. And it worked well.
And the kbps is moving. Now the items that shutdown timer is listing doesn't respond when Im downloading something. What might be the cause of this?How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a [known issue](http://www.sinvise.net/home/projects/software/shutdown-timer#comment-101):

Apparently 2.5 does what you want:

[image]

Comment: is this compatible on 64 bit w7?